# como puedo duplicar la misma fecha en html con java script

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Lo que quiero es obtener la misma fecha pero si agrego otra no me da ya intente cambiar de nombre de los métodos y solo me da la fecha que asigno Apenas estoy entrando en web y no entiendo mucho si alguien me ayuda se lo agradeceria mucho ya que soy inexperto pero trato de aprender si me recomiendan un tutorial o  un libro alguien seria de mucha ayuda gracias

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Hola nelly</h4>

                <Asunto>Asunto :
                    <input type="text" name="Asunto " size="40" placeholder="Escriba a qui el asunto "></input>
                </Asunto>

                <P ALIGN="LEFT">Mensaje </P>
                <textarea name="textarea" rows="100" cols="100" style=" width: 567px; height: 261px;" placeholder="Escriba a qui el Mensaje  "></textarea>
   <br>
                <!-------------- -->
                <label for="start">Fecha inicio:</label>

                <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22">
    <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22">

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Enviar </button>
                </div>

                <script>
                    var f = new Date();
                    var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
     var dateContro2 = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
                    var fecha = ((f.getFullYear()) + "-" + (f.getMonth()) + 1 + "-" + (f.getDate()));
                    
      dateControl.value = fecha;
                    dateControl.setAttribute("min", fecha);
                    dateControl.setAttribute("max", fecha);
     
     
                </script>

            </div>
   

        </div>
```

Comment: ve a [ask], edita y mejora tu pregunta... también puedes hacer un [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla...

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. en español. Puedes ser mas claro con la preguntas? quieres obtener la misma fecha? tienes dos inputs. Donde la quieres obtener? Y dices *pero si agrego otra no me da* . Se mas claro con la pregunta por favor, nos ayudara a darte una mejor respuesta. Estaba por responderlo en base a algunos detalles de tu código, pero tal como está me es complicado darte una respuesta precisa. Mientras es necesario aclarar que tienes dos inputs con el mismo ID. también aclarar que tus últimos dos seteos de atributos son los que te impiden cambiar los valores. (Siempre tendrán el día de hoy)

Answer (score 0):

En el html primero que nada defines dos input con el mismo id. Eso si bien te lo permite hacer no es correcto.

Luego, para el acceso al Dom, en vez de utilizar javascript directamente utiliza jquery (u otro, jquery es simple de aprender).
Este framework no solo te ayudara en la simpleza de tu código, sino que te permitirá ser multibrowser. Si todo lo haces con javascript puro, vas a tener que hacer distinciones entre un navegador y otro.
Para el manejo de fechas en javascript, utiliza la librería moments (te facilitará la vida vas a ver)

Si quieres un tutorial puede utlizar:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Espero te sirva y cualquier cosa a las órdenes!!

Comment: Decir que con usar JS vas a tener que hacer distinciones entre navegadores a estas fechas es parcialmente falso (salvo que le des soporte a navegadores muy viejos), JQuery que no es un framework sino una biblioteca de utilidades ya no brinda algo que con las nuevas características de ES6+ se puede hacer

Comment: Que tal Eduardo, seria bueno que vayas a [answer] y lo leas... te ayudara a mejorar tu respuesta, tal como esta tu respuesta se sugiere a si mismo como un comentario, y los comentarios deben ir en su respectiva sección... para que tu respuesta sea aceptada por la comunidad seria bueno que des una solución clara y concreta, y si es posible subas en código funcional para un mejor entendimiento de lo que dices... mucha suerte